# Rotate svg elements around multiple axis

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I am creating an animation of a flying drone and I need the two wings to rotate around two different axis.

This is what I have so far but it seems to be buggy and not rotating correcly. What shall I do to improve?

```css
  .drone .body {
   z-index: 1;
   color: #050423;
  }

  .drone .wing {
   top: 1px;
   color: #000000;
    transform-origin: center;
  }

  .drone.animate .wing {
   animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes wing {
   100% {
    transform: rotateY(7200deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
  <svg class="drone animate" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 20">
    <g>
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
      <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/>    </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
      <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9
       c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5
       C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0
       c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5
       c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: you need `transform-box: fill-box;`

Answer (score 2):

In the image below, the red frame shows the borders of the SVG canvas

[image]

You need to expand the SVG canvas a bit and place the drone in the center `viewBox="-3 -3 60 20"`

As commented @Temani Afif - `transform-box: fill-box;` for the symmetrical rotation of the propeller screws, this is necessary

```
.wing {
    fill: #000;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
  }
```

To paint svg elements use `fill` attribute instead of `color`

*Below is the full code:*

```css
.drone .body {
   fill: #050423;
  }

   .wing {
   fill: #000;
    transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
  }

  .drone.animate .wing {
   animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes wing {
   100% {
    transform: rotateY(7200deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<svg class="drone animate"  height="20vh" viewBox="-3 -3 60 20">
    <g>
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
      <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/>    </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
      <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9
       c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5
       C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0
       c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5
       c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```